# Given a sorted array nums, remove the duplicates in-place

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, python-2.x, interview-questions

I wrote an algorithm to solve this challenge but would love some feedback on its efficiency and, if you were an interviewer, what your opinion would be on my solution. I believe my time complexity is \$O(N)\$. Is this correct?

**The Task:**

> Given a sorted array *nums*, remove the duplicates in-place such that
>   each element appear only once and return the new length.
>
> Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by
>   modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.
>
> > **Example:**
> >     Given *nums* = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
> >
> > Your function should return length = 5, with the first five elements of *nums* being modified to 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 respectively.
> >
> > It doesn't matter what values are set in the array beyond the returned length.

**My Solution:**

```
def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """
    if(nums):
        IndFirstKind = IndCompare = 0
        lengthArray = len(nums)
        while(IndCompare < lengthArray):
            if nums[IndFirstKind] == nums[IndCompare]:
                IndCompare = IndCompare + 1
            else:
                if(IndFirstKind + 1 != IndCompare):
                    temp = nums[IndCompare]
                    nums[IndCompare] = nums[IndFirstKind + 1]
                    nums[IndFirstKind + 1]= temp
                IndFirstKind = IndFirstKind +1
                IndCompare = IndCompare + 1
        return IndFirstKind + 1
    return 0
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
i = 0
for key, _ in groupby(nums):
    nums[i] = key
    i += 1
return i
```

A look at the implementation of [`groupby`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L11) shows that it allocates \$O(1)\$ extra space, as required by the problem.

The `i += 1` could be avoided using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), like this:

```
i = -1 # in case nums is empty
for i, (key, _) in enumerate(groupby(nums)):
    nums[i] = key
return i + 1
```

but the need for an exceptional case to handle empty input is rather inelegant.

Answer (score 2):

`while` loops are not that common in Python. Instead, we prefer to iterate over elements directly using `for` loops.

In your case, using a running index of last modified value, you can compare the current value with the last modified to easily skip duplicates:

```
index_to_update = 0
for element in nums:
    if element > nums[index_to_update]:
        index_to_update += 1
        nums[index_to_update] = element
```

this approach store the number of elements updated in `index_to_update` but the first element (`0` in your example) is never updated as it will never be strictly greater than the front of the list. So you need to account for it manually in your return value:

```
return index_to_update + 1
```

However, this approach lead to wrong results with empty lists, so you also have to take it into account:

```
def remove_duplicates(nums):
    if not nums:
        return 0

    index_to_update = 0
    for element in nums:
        if element > nums[index_to_update]:
            index_to_update += 1
            nums[index_to_update] = element

    return index_to_update + 1
```

Note the use of snake_case in the name of the function as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines. I also removed `self` to make this a regular function as there is absolutely no need to have this in a class.

Answer (score 0):

- Flat is better than nested. Consider reverting the first `if` condition:

  ```
  if not nums:
      return 0

  # main logic goes here, less one indentation level
  ```
- An `if-else` as a body of the loop is always a red flag. In this case he body of the `while` loop is better expressed by another loop: we want to skip all dups of `nums[intFirstKind]`. Consider

  ```
      while (nums[indFirstKind] == nums[indCompare]:
          indCompare += 1
  ```

  You may want to go an extra mile and factor this in a function. `skipDuplicates` looks like a good name. BTW, what would be the parameters? what shall it return?
- Swapping `nums[indCompare]` with `nums[indFirstKind + 1]` seems like a pure waste of time. If however you insist on swapping, do it in a pythonic way:

  ```
  nums[indCompare], nums[indFirstKind + 1] = nums[indFirstKind + 1], nums[indCompare]
  ```

---

All that said, the solution should be along the lines of

```
    indCopyTo = 0
    indFirstKind = 0
    indCompare = 1

    while indCompare < len(nums):
        nums[indCopyTo] = nums[indFirstKind]
        indCopyTo += 1
        while nums[indFirstKind] == nums[indCompare]:
            indCompare += 1
        indFirstKind = indCompare
    return indCopyTo
```